# Performance of $in when querying Mongo

Tags: mongodb

At the moment I am testing the performance of a Mongo query using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/), however I am using a test environment and we do not have all the same data we do in production. As a result, most of the records are not found during the query (but I expect most of them to be in production).

My question is this: Will the performance change depending on how many records are found?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you have created the index on the key you are going to put for $in query. So in that case it will have the time complexity of Log(n) where n will be the number of records in the collection which i think is the best complexity you can get.

But if you are asking about the data that will be returned from the DB server to the application server , yes it will have the impact but i think it should not be significant in todays time.